# Can we control a robot using an Android phone?

Tags: android, robot

After stepping into the world of Android, I wondered if an Android phone can be used as a remote to control a basic pick and place robot . If just an SMS could be send to control the action of a robot like say "pick object 1 at distance x" would result in the bot performing the specified action.

Yes, It will involve Artificial Intelligence coupled with the basics of developing a robot but then I wanted to know whether it's possible to develop a machine like this ? If yes , how should one kickstart things ? Would Android ADK be helpful ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cellbots](http://www.cellbots.com/) Has what you are looking for. They have several different platforms set up using various control methods(lego NXT, arduino, etc.) Many of them are able to be controlled either remotely, or even with an onboard Android device.

Comment: Yes Cellbots definitely has giving my project a new direction. Thanks for the reply !! :)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'd recommend knowing how to do it with a computer first. Once you know that, learn how to program Android (that's what we're here for) and get started. Hell, you could make an application to control it - that might be more impressive.

Edit: if you're controlling it via SMS, why are you limited to Android? All of the coding for that would be done on the side of the robot, and you'd have to assign a number for that. I'd recommend an application and communicate via WIFI or Bluetooth.

Comment: Using a computer to control robot is indeed challenging but at the same time quite common and existing . I ain't limiting myself to Android in any which way, it's just that I feel the I could do my best using an Android phone at disposal using the features it provides . Yes the programming will be on the side of the robot , but still I would be required to write small amount of code on my phone also which perhaps may be the most prominent aspect if the project happens to be successful

Comment: I'm not following: if you are sending an SMS what would you need to program on your phone?

Comment: No I wasn't referring to the SMS code over there, instead I was talking about the connection code that would help me connect my WiFi enabled phone to a bot in a much secure and efficient manner.

Answer (score 1):

i dont think it would be SMS
seeing as though your robot would need a phone number to receive

but something like bluetooth might work
or maybe even wifi

what would be really cool is that those r standards
which means if u got it working
any bluetooth or wifi device could control it given that you created an app for it

at this point it would be basic tcp/ip control (idk what protocol bluetooth uses though)

Comment: Yes agreed I would love to develop it for a specific standard like Bluetooth. For me the communication part seems a bit tough simply because I have never tried such things before. Well, I have developed simple line followers in the past but then building one that works over Bluetooth/ WiFi would be really challenging . Any idea on how this could be done by beginners like me ?

Comment: way out of my league, this is more electrical engineering stuff.  i figure u could take 2 routes.  either a proprietary wifi and mobo or you would just hook a laptop/premade device into it (say usb) then write a server application and client app to communicate with it via tcp/ip.  i do know though that they have custom receivers and chips that you would directly integrate with your robot.  in all honesty you would probably do better going to ur local collage and ask a grad student(EE major).

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of good ideas, but you don't really need Android in here. Coz I see that you choose your robot stimulus is SMS. Every mobile device can send SMS, right? 
By the way, your robot has to include a device with can receive SMS. SMS has a advantage that it can be sent very very far. If you don't need to control your robot that far, try another connection like Wifi, Bluetooth, etc.
If you stick with SMS choice, take a look at [this](http://www.mycollegeproject.com/GSM%20%28SMS%29%20Controlled%20Wireless%20Robot.html).
And search "SMS robot controller" for a start ;). Have fun and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use SMS, use bluetooth or similar. Code the robot to understand the same functions it would if you were using a computer to control it (or really any kind of control) and then set up the controls on an app on the android device. Up, Down, Left, Right, Forward, Backward, Pick, Place and anything else you'd need. Make the button presses send what the robot it looking for for each action.

Answer (score 1):

All depends on 1. tasks you're making your robot for, 2. the Android phone itself, as its CPU might not be enough for the tasks set. Once you've made this two points clear – the tutorials are hardly scarce. As for the good ones, a starting guide on [how to build and program a robot which can recognize and follow a human](http://cases.azoft.com/using-android-smartphones-as-robot-brains/); with performance tests for various Android devices by HTC, Huawei and Samsung.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new in the field of robotics and Android, controlling a robot by SMS is not a small project. You can start by using the Bluetooth technology in order to control a robot and the step into the SMS method. There are several ways to control a robot using an Android device: Bluetooth, Internet, by using the USB port, or sounds emitted by the device.

A good article about tutorials to [control a robot using the Bluetooth technology](http://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-develop-simple-bluetooth-android-application-to-control-a-robot-remote/)

Answer (score 0):

i developed what you are asking for, now my android can control RC car remotely  and also controlling a cam in it .tools Arduino ,Bluetooth device android and other things